# Django ORM key error with lost MySql connection

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models, amazon-aurora

This is the environment:

1. AWS Aurora database compatible with MySql.
2. Django 2.0.3 (Python 3.6)
3. Pip-Mysql dependencies: django-mysql==2.2.2, mysqlclient==1.3.12.
4. Master-Slave database configuration.

It seems that django or mysql engine always fails on certain queries resulting in this specific error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
>   line 158, in **get**
>       rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)   File "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py",
>   line 13, in get_cached_value
>       return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name] KeyError: 'assigned_to'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
>   line 71, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
>   line 253, in execute
>       self._warning_check()   File "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
>   line 148, in _warning_check
>       warnings = db.show_warnings()   File "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 381, in show_warnings
>       self.query("SHOW WARNINGS")   File "/home/ubuntu/ivs/vpython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 277, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Yes, one of my models have "assigend_to" field which is a foreign key. But why does it fail with a KeyError?

Did anyone have any similar KeyErrors and MySql lost connections as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, what actually was happening is this:

1. I was making queries with reverse-foreign keys.
2. Objects returned with with reverse-foreign keys contained some other foreign keys.
3. When I tried to access them e.g. 'assigned_to' i got this exception every time.

Answer (score 1):

In official MySQL definition, there is a [specific page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-lost-connection.html) about this error. As can be seen from here in detail, here are what you should try:

1. The "during query" term in your error might be connected with a timeout caused by processing millions of rows. You can increase `net_read_timeout` to 60 seconds etc.
2. This can happen when you are trying the initial connection but in your case this is impossible.

Comment: As what you are saying is true, but this was totally unrelated. Please read my answer below.